# OpenMP paralellized C++ code exhibits higher execution times on more threads?

Tags: c++, openmp, numerical-integration

I'm trying to learn paralellization of C++ using openmp,  and I'm trying to use the following example. But for some reason when I increase the number of threads the code runs slower. Im compiling it using the `-fopenmp` flag. It would be nice if I could get your expert opinion.

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <iostream>
static long num_steps =100000000; 
#define NUM_THREADS 4

double  step;
int main(){
    int i,nthreads;
    double pi, sum[NUM_THREADS]; // should be shared : hence promoted scalar sum into an array
   
    step  = 1.0/(double) num_steps;
    omp_set_num_threads(NUM_THREADS);

    double t1 = omp_get_wtime();
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
    int i, id, nthrds;
    double x;
    id = omp_get_thread_num();
    nthrds = omp_get_num_threads();
    //if(id==0) nthreads = nthrds; // This is done because the number of threads can be different
                                 // ie the environment can give you a different number of threads
                                 // than  requested

    for(i=id, sum[id] = 0.0; i<num_steps;i=i+nthrds){

        x = (i+0.5)*step;
        sum[id] += 4.0/(1.0+x*x);
    }
    }

    double t2 = omp_get_wtime();

    std::cout << "Time : " ;

    double ms_double = t2 - t1;

    std::cout << ms_double << "ms\n";

    for(i=0,pi=0.0; i < nthreads; i++){
        pi += sum[i]*step;
    }
}
```

Comment: Within a parallel block you only initialize `nthreads` if `id==0`, but then read it in every case? I'm no OMP expert, but that doesn't look good.

Comment: `nthreads` is only initialzed in the thread with `id == 0` but uninitialized in all others. Why do you use 3 different variables for number of threads? `NUM_THREADS`, `nthreads` and `nthrds` ?

Comment: Synchronization between threads has a cost. Scheduling threads has a cost. Spawning and deleting threads has a cost. If your threads are not doing a significant amount of work that makes up for the cost of creating, deleting, managing them as well as the cost of them communicating (which includes synchronization) - how can it be a big surprise that adding threads can reduce performance?

Comment: Don't use it. If function name permutations do different things, it is terrible api design lol. Compare `omp_get_thread_num` and `omp_get_num_threads`. It's like they hired a 3 year old to pick the names.

Comment: You should create a local variable to keep your sum and then write it back to `sum[id]` at the end of your parallel block otherwise you'll get into a situation called false sharing which would degrade performance significantly.

Comment: Unrelated: note that using `-ffastmath` help the compiler to vectorize the loop which is not (fully) possible for the compiler by default. This should be something like twice faster, and even faster on recent Intel hardware. Note this can impact the result though (they can be better in this specific case for the first iterations, but also possibly worse for the last ones).

Answer (score 2):

Minor complaints aside, your big problem is the loop update `i=i+nthrds`. This means that each cache line will be accessed by all 4 of your threads. (Btw, use the `OMP_NUM_THREADS` environment variable to set the number of threads. Do not hardcode.) This is called false sharing and it's really bad for performance: you want each cacheline to be exclusively in one core.

Comment: In fact, the `sum` array is also read/written so that false sharing occurs. This one can be easily fixed using a thread-local variable.

Comment: Note that `i` is declared twice: outside and inside the parallel region, which can be confusing and very easy to overlook. The declaration inside the parallel region makes it a private variable, so it does not cause any false sharing or data-race.

Answer (score 1):

The main advantage of OpenMP is that you do not have to do reduction manually. You just have to add an extra line to the serial code. So, your code should be something like this (which is free from false-sharing):

```
double sum=0;
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)
    for(unsigned long i=0; i<num_steps; ++i){
        const double x = (i+0.5)*step;
        sum += 4.0/(1.0+x*x);
    }
double pi = sum*step;
```

Note that your code had an uninitialized variable (`pi`) and your code did not handle the properly if you got less threads than requested.

Answer (score 0):

What @Victor Ejkhout called "minor complaints" might not be so minor. It is only normal that using a new API (omp) for the first time can be confusing. And that reflects on the coding style of the application code as well, more often than not. But especially in such cases, special attention should be paid to readability.

The code below is the "prettied-up" version of your attempt. And next to the omp parallel integration it also has the single threaded and a multi threaded (using `std::thread`) version so you can compare them to each other.

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

constexpr int MAX_PARALLEL_THREADS = 4; // long is wrong - is it an isize_t or a int32_t or an int64_t???

// the function we want to integrate
double f(double x) {
  return 4.0 / (1.0 + x * x);
}

// performs the summation of function values on the interval [left,right[
double sum_interval(double left, double right, double step) {
  double sum = 0.0;
  for (double x = left; x < right; x += step) {
    sum += f(x);
  }
  return sum;
}

double integrate_single_threaded(double left, double right, double step) {
  return sum_interval(left, right, step) / (right - left);
}

double integrate_multi_threaded(double left, double right, double step) {
  double sums[MAX_PARALLEL_THREADS];
  std::thread threads[MAX_PARALLEL_THREADS];
  for (int i= 0; i < MAX_PARALLEL_THREADS;i++) {
    threads[i] = std::thread( [&sums,left,right,step,i] () {
      double ileft = left + (right - left) / MAX_PARALLEL_THREADS * i;
      double iright = left + (right - left) / MAX_PARALLEL_THREADS * (i + 1);
      sums[i] = sum_interval(ileft,iright,step);
    });
  }
  double total_sum = 0.0;
  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_PARALLEL_THREADS; i++) {
    threads[i].join();
    total_sum += sums[i];
  }
  return total_sum / (right - left);
}

double integrate_parallel(double left, double right, double step) {
  double sums[MAX_PARALLEL_THREADS];
  int thread_count = 0;

  omp_set_num_threads(MAX_PARALLEL_THREADS);
  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    thread_count = omp_get_num_threads(); // 0 is impossible, there is always 1 thread minimum...
    int interval_index = omp_get_thread_num();
    double ileft = left + (right - left) / thread_count * interval_index;
    double iright = left + (right - left) / thread_count * (interval_index + 1);
    sums[interval_index] = sum_interval(ileft,iright,step);
  }
  
  double total_sum = 0.0;
  for (int i = 0; i < thread_count; i++) {
    total_sum += sums[i];
  }
  return total_sum / (right - left);
}

int main (int argc, const char* argv[]) {
  double left = -1.0;
  double right = 1.0;
  double step = 1.0E-9;

  // run single threaded calculation
  std::cout << "single" << std::endl;
  double tstart = omp_get_wtime();
  double i_single = integrate_single_threaded(left, right, step);
  double tend = omp_get_wtime();
  double st_time = tend - tstart;

  // run multi threaded calculation
  std::cout << "multi" << std::endl;
  tstart = omp_get_wtime();
  double i_multi = integrate_multi_threaded(left, right, step);
  tend = omp_get_wtime();
  double mt_time = tend - tstart;

  // run omp calculation
  std::cout << "omp" << std::endl;
  tstart = omp_get_wtime();
  double i_omp = integrate_parallel(left, right, step);
  tend = omp_get_wtime();
  double omp_time = tend - tstart;
  
  std::cout
    << "i_single: " << i_single
    << " st_time: " << st_time << std::endl
    << "i_multi: " << i_multi
    << " mt_time: " << mt_time << std::endl
    << "i_omp: " << i_omp
    << " omp_time: " << omp_time << std::endl;
  
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile this on my Debian with `g++ --std=c++17 -Wall -O3 -lpthread -fopenmp -o para para.cpp -pthread`, I get the following results:

> single
> multi
> omp
> i_single: 3.14159e+09 st_time: 2.37662
> i_multi: 3.14159e+09 mt_time: 0.635195
> i_omp: 3.14159e+09 omp_time: 0.660593

So, at least my conclusion is, that it is not worth the effort to learn openMP, given that the (more general use) `std::thread` version looks just as nice and performs at least equally well.

I am not really trusting the computed integral result in either case, though. But I did not really focus on that. They all produce the same value. That is the important part.

Comment: I may have been a bit hasty in my analysis of that code. Thanks for cleaning it up explicitly.